# rails 3.1 scss and where does compass fit in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, compass-sass

I am creating a new theme for my cms using scss.   I am currently on rails 3.0.7 but am going to upgrade to 3.1 as soon as the the final is released so i can use the asset pipeline stuff.

My question is where does compass fit into rails 3.1 ?   is it still useful / needed?

Does it work with 3.1 ?  Has anyone got any experience with this or any alternative?

thanks 
rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only use compass to include files, then it is not necessary, but Compass is much more than that. Compass is a Framework that includes tested patterns for creating multi browser stylesheets. It also makes is extremely simple to create sprites.

For example:

`.simple   { @include border-radius(4px, 4px); }`

will produce:

```
.simple {
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px / 4px;
 -o-border-radius: 4px / 4px;
 -ms-border-radius: 4px / 4px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 4px / 4px;
 border-radius: 4px / 4px; 
}
```

If you are unclear of the value of Compass, I would recommend reading the [guides](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/).

Currently Compass is mostly supported by Rails 3.1.RC4 by adding the following gems:

```
gem "compass", :git => 'git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git', :branch => 'rails31'
gem 'sass-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git'
```

Comment: The rails31 branch has been merged into master now, here is the [latest compass install guide](https://gist.github.com/1184843) for Rails 3.1.